# Predicting Value in multi-dimension data

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-models

I need help with my data,
I mix 2 different powder materials to get one powder with a specific quality number. So, this resulted in quality numbers depending on 4 features, the quality of materials 1 and 2, and their percentage. I created small data set with it.
This is not linear, but I want to predict values, for mixing other 2 powders and get the resulting powder quality.
Which model to use and how to train my ML model?

Comment: This is formulated way to abstract! Can you tell us some context&details, in a down-to-earth language?